# Deleted App-Folder of Magento Installation

Tags: magento

While installing some plugin I've followed the tutorial of this and it told me to insert an folder named "App" into my root directory. After this nothing worked any more. That means I deleted the original "App"-Folder of my Magento Installation. My question is now:

Is there any possibility to access my installation ?

If not, is there any way to "save" my shop. That means the categories, attributes, products, and so on...

In Advance, thanks for your help...

Comment: Ask your hosting provider to restore a backup of your shop.

Comment: Thanks for this input, but i forgot to mention that it was a locale version that should go online at the end of the week....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you should get the downloader screen when your app dir is gone. If not: check your version, get the original app folder, reinstall this folder, change the data in local.xml and if you did not have any (custom) modules you're back on track. As long as your Media folder and database is intact, other shop data is safe.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. That is what I just tried, but it does not work for me. Perhaps I did some mistakes. I got the download screen and downloaded the data, after this I installed a magento shop on a new database. Then I copied the app folder into my damaged installation and changed "dbname" "username" "userpassword"... but if i try to go to my localhost:8888 page I got Error 503 :-/

Comment: I have forgotten about my own styled template because of this my webshop was not back on track, but your solution should work in general. thanks for this